# In python, using the scipy library - how to determine the offset position of the correlated signals?

Tags: python, scipy, position, offset

I am in need of the "offset position" of the correlated signal **x** in the time series shown in the **image** below. The lag between series x and y is correctly calculated from scipy's signal.correlate function as -86 points.

[image: Time Series Analysis]

Below is a plot of the array returned from scipy.correlations() which is double the length of the original array size for x and y.  The peak of the correlation is located at position 2914.

[image]

Below is a close up of the two series (x an y).
[image]

Comment: You could take the max of the first signal, get that position, then subtract the lag to get the offset position.

Comment: In your tags it would be more informative to use something like `signal` or `scipy-signal` (if it exists).  `offset` is too generic a tag, that can apply to many different contexts.

Comment: I tried to use signal in the TAG but it did not exist and I don't have enough points to create one.

Comment: Brock, some of the correlated signals in my data are not pronounced as in the provided example (buried in the data).  Therefore, I need to know exactly where the correlation function found the solution.